# Regarding NVL function

Tags: sql, oracle

I use a simple SQL with `NVL`, but the query is not showing the result properly. My requirement is if `Shipment_refnum_qual_gid` is 'ULA/SAO.UL_ONU' then take the value of this `refnum` otherwise show `NULL` in the result.

Sample query is below.

```
SELECT NVL (SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_VALUE, 'NULL') 
FROM SHIPMENT_REFNUM SRF, SHIPMENT SH 
WHERE SRF.SHIPMENT_GID= SH.SHIPMENT_GID AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000057288' 
AND SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'ULA/SAO.UL_ONU
```

Comment: SELECT NVL (SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_VALUE, 'NULL') FROM SHIPMENT_REFNUM SRF, SHIPMENT SH
WHERE SRF.SHIPMENT_GID= SH.SHIPMENT_GID
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000057288'
AND SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'ULA/SAO.UL_ONU'

Comment: FWIW, `NVL()` is an Oracle function, not standard SQL. The standard SQL equivalent function is `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have a `NVL` function. Instead, use `IFNULL`:

```
select ifnull(SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_VALUE, 'NULL')
  from SHIPMENT_REFNUM SRF, SHIPMENT SH
  where SRF.SHIPMENT_GID= SH.SHIPMENT_GID
    and SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000057288'
    and SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'ULA/SAO.UL_ONU'
```

**EDIT**

As you said in the comments, that there is no matching entry in `SHIPMENT_REFNUM` for one ore more values in `SHIPMENT`, but you want those entries to be included, you need an outer join:

```
select ifnull(SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_VALUE, 'NULL')
  from SHIPMENT_REFNUM SRF
  right outer join SHIPMENT SH on SRF.SHIPMENT_GID= SH.SHIPMENT_GID
  where SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000057288'
    and SRF.SHIPMENT_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'ULA/SAO.UL_ONU'
```

Comment: No actually I am not using this query in MySQL and by mistake i tagged my question as MySQL so please consider this as a normal SQL query where NVL works.

Comment: Then it should work as expected. What is in the output? Are you sure that your source data is `NULL` - maybe it's only an empty string?

Comment: Yes you are right here is what is happening in the query.

Comment: Shipment_refnum_qual_gid is ULA/SAO.UL_ONU but this refnum is not present in the shipment ''ULA/SAO.5000057288'' so nothing output will be a empty string so now tell me how we can handle this???

Comment: Ah, ok, you do an inner join of `SHIPMENT_REFNUM` and `SHIPMENT` which only return rows for those entries, which have `SRF.SHIPMENT_GID= SH.SHIPMENT_GID`. You need an outer join to get empty (NULL) values if no matching entry in your second table exist. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354 how to do that.